# How would I say 'home state' in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests, word-usage

I'm looking for home state or really any Japanese equivalent meaning? I'm trying to explain why I love my hoodie with Wisconsin across the front. If there isn't one I could always just reword my sentence but I was curious and couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an easy question because there are no "states" in Japan, but to talk about what U.S. state someone is from, we would use:

> 「出身州{しゅっしんしゅう}」

More informally:

> 「生{う}まれた州{しゅう}」

Comment: Genuine question from some-one living in the sticks (田舎). Do people often use 出身州? I would probably just say 私の出身地/地元はインディアナ州. Should I be using出身州 instead?